# Setup arara with xindy

Tags: pdftex, xindy, arara

How do I set up arara to work with xindy? I tried using xindy.yaml from https://github.com/cereda/arara/blob/master/rules/xindy.yaml as the TeXLive 2017 distribution does not come with xindy.yaml.
Then I called arara from my .tex file like this:

```
% arara: xindy: {modules: [texindy, page-ranges, xindystyle], codepage: utf8, language: german-duden }
```

I received the following error:

```
ERROR Arara - Directive 'xindy' at line 7 has an invalid argument type. Only the arguments 'files' and 'items' can have a list. Both are reserved arara keywords.
```

How can I parse multiple modules to be called?
The goal is to start xindy with the following parameters:

```
xindy -M texindy -M page-ranges -M xindystyle -C utf8 -L german-duden file.tex
```

Comment: Works fine for me (except I don't have your `xindystyle.xdy` module) with arara v4.0. If you're using the `arara` version distributed with TeX Live, then you likely have only v3.0 in which case the new v4.0 may be incompatible.

Comment: I do have the preinstaleld version 3.0 and I cannot find any newer version on github (https://github.com/cereda/arara).

Comment: Only the source code is on github. v4.0 is still in development.